get channel's content owner details with youtube API and curl
I was going through the YouTube API documents and came across the channel:list reference document: youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
I'd like to pull the content owner details from a specified YouTube channel using my curl code.
Here's my curl command:
# However, it always returns an empty string. I've tried with multiple channel IDs.
curl --location 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentOwnerDetails&key=[API_KEY]&id=UCvM5YYWwfLwpcQgbRr68JLQ'

My goal is to retrieve the channel information such as name, email ID, and links (similar to what we can retrieve from the YouTube channel's About section).
If you all can help, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I ran the following command
curl --location 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentOwnerDetails&key=[API_KEY]&id=UCvM5YYWwfLwpcQgbRr68JLQ'

I was expecting a content inside the contentOwnerDetails property but it always return empty
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "z0I3zGztxz3-74qx8qj5hFP6RBM",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "83Fm0SWd-LmfdGWzC7EI2FDjJDE",
            "id": "UCvM5YYWwfLwpcQgbRr68JLQ",
            "contentOwnerDetails": {}
        }
    ]
}


Does this answer meets your needs? Note that concerning the email retrieval, it is secured by a captcha so you cannot retrieve it automatically.
